# how to activate a python project through a picture

Tags: python, image

I am making a project for school and I wanted to insert a python file with a code I'm writing into a picture so that when someone else opens the picture the code will run.
My ideas were steganography and write/read but not sure how I can implement them into my solution.
any suggestions or ideas are welcomed

Comment: there is an entire industry dedicated to preventing you from doing things like this

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/81677/how-is-it-possible-to-embed-executable-code-in-an-image